# Get SelectedItem from a nested RepeaterView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using [DottorPagliaccius repeater view](https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin-Custom-Controls) thats nested inside another repeaterview.  The command RSSFeedSelectedCommand doesnt work unless on top repeater, which in theory makes sense but how can i get it to work?

I have looked into using Converters and bindtoeventcommand but cant see to get them working.

```
<repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater" SeparatorHeight="25" ItemsSource={Binding Feeds}">
    <repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Spacing="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Blue" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="12" />
                    <repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater2" EmptyText="No elements" ShowSeparator="true" SeparatorHeight="2" SeparatorColor="Silver" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItemCommand="{Binding RSSFeedSelectedCommand}">
                        <repeater`enter code here`:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image.Url}"></Image>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                    </repeater:RepeaterView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
</repeater:RepeaterView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Repeater was trying to find the command in `Feeds` however exists in the ViewModel.

```
<repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater2" EmptyText="No elements" ShowSeparator="true" SeparatorHeight="2" SeparatorColor="Silver" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItemCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference RSSPage}, Path=BindingContext.RSSFeedSelectedCommand}">
```

and you have to name the page:

```
<ContentPage x:Name="PageName" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If my assumption is correct, your class structure should be something like,

```
ViewModel
  |__List of Feeds
    |__List of Items
  |__RSSFeedSelectedCommand
```

So, `DataContext` of your inner repeater control (`MainRepeater2`) will be `Feed`. So, try with `DataContext` of outer repeater control. Like,

```
<repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
   SelectedItemCommand="{Binding DataContext.RSSFeedSelectedCommand,
                                 ElementName=MainRepeater}"/>
```

For *Xamarin*:

```
<repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
   SelectedItemCommand="{Binding DataContext.RSSFeedSelectedCommand, 
                                 Source={x:Reference MainRepeater}}"/>
```

Comment: Yep that how my class structure is, however 'ElementName' has not been implemented for xamarin i believe, see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36049/using-elementname-on-binding-gives-me-an-error)

Comment: @Bish25 You're right. Can you try this?     `<repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainRepeater2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItemCommand="{Binding DataContext.RSSFeedSelectedCommand, Source={x:Reference MainRepeater}}"/>`

Comment: thanks for the help, Just tried this and still didn't work. also tried adding `InputTransparent="true"` on the Main Repeater but no luck

Comment: @Bish25 I didn't have *Xamarin* set up in my machine to test it. Can you try setting `DataContext={Binding}` it your `MainRepeater` and check.

Comment: Thanks for helping, managed to help get me to the answer. i posted the solution :)